# How to remove or keep specific cached files/ data in Android Webview?

Tags: android, caching, webview, clear-cache

I want to clear cache but I need to have specific data or file where sessions are stored. Basically, I do `webView.clearCache(true);` but this clears all the cache. I am calling server where I need to auto login, but since cache is cleared, I cannot autologin and hence the hiccup. Please suggest ways to tackle this??